# Jquery fadeout on click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Anyone knows what's wrong here?

Javascript

```
function editDayClicked() {

var leftsideB = $(".BtnAbsLeftPos");
var rightsideB = $(".BtnAbsRightPos");

leftsideB.fadeOut({ queue: false, duration: 1500 });
rightsideB.fadeOut({ queue: false, duration: 1500 });

leftsideB.animate({ left: '-6%' }, 1500);
rightsideB.animate({ left: '100%' }, 1500,
    function () {
        $("#UserCalendar").fadeOut({ duration: 1500 });
        $("#UserDayData").fadeOut({ duration: 1500 });
    });
}
```

This function is inserted on a click button through code behind C#, when certains events occur.

C#

```
protected void UserCalendar_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    EditDay.Enabled = true;
    EditDay.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:editDayClicked(); return true;");

    currentDate.Text = UserCalendar.SelectedDate.ToLongDateString();
}
```

However when the button is clicked, the function is called, but nothing happens. After that I have also the button click in code behind. I leave you all the code related:

ASPX

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="EditDay" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/EditB.png" CssClass="GenericButton" Enabled="false" ToolTip="Edit the current day" OnClick="EditDay_Click" />
```

C#

```
protected void EditDay_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    Response.Redirect("DayTasks.aspx?day=" + UserCalendar.SelectedDate.Day);            
}
```

**EDITED (21/02/2017):**

Ok guys, Now I realised that the real problem is on the wrapper. I have also a celandar and I use an AJAX updatePanel, to prevent the page from being refreshed when I'm clicking on the calendar days...and that's the whole problem. I tried it in an empty project without the update panel and works fine. I do not know why the updatepanel is interfering. Any ideas why this is happening and any workarounds to solve it?...I'm sorry I did not clarify at first.

Thanks for your inestimable support.

Answer (score 0):

as your code shows, onCLick do a function that contains definition of event, so i belive that you dont understan event on html
so your code in onload of jquery will be:

```
$(window).load(onLoad);
function onLoad() {

$("#UserCalendar").fadeOut({ duration: 1500 });
$("#UserDayData").fadeOut({ duration: 1500 }, "swing",
    function () {
        var leftsideB = $(".BtnAbsLeftPos");
        var rightsideB = $(".BtnAbsRightPos");

        leftsideB.fadeOut({ queue: false, duration: 1500 });
        rightsideB.fadeOut({ queue: false, duration: 1500 });

        leftsideB.animate({ left: '-6%' }, 1500);
        rightsideB.animate({ left: '100%' }, 1500);
    });

//alert('faded out');
}
```

This make, when page is loaded, the events is defined, so when is trigger by click, it will be dispatched.

AT last, this code, will be no necessary:

```
EditDay.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:editDayClicked(); return true;");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I know, disable or invisible ASP elements does not appear in the HTML code, so you cannot attach any javascript to an element that does not exist. I put the enable and the attachment right after do some code (it has to be like this), otherwise I dont want to execute the javascript on click. Anyway I got your point, but the function raises well, the problem is that the content dont. I do not know if I confusing myslef...

Comment: if you want, i belive both are spanish talkers

Comment: Yes I am and believe you are too....I just keep writting in English cause we are in a English forum.

Comment: use private channel for speak, ok?

Comment: Sure, which one do you prefer?

Comment: today im busy  sorry